# Why clap contains_id() always returns TRUE?

Tags: rust, clap

This is the code (I'm using [clap 3.2.20](https://docs.rs/crate/clap/3.2.20)):

```
pub fn main() {
  let m = Command::new("foo")
    .arg(
      Arg::new("bar")
        .long("bar")
        .required(false)
        .action(ArgAction::SetTrue)
      )
    .get_matches();
  if m.contains_id("bar") {
    println!("Boom!");
  }
}
```

It prints `Boom!` either I provide `--bar` option or not. Why and how to fix?

Comment: As I see on the docs is the behaviour of [`SetTrue`](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/builder/enum.ArgAction.html#variant.SetTrue). `contains_id()` returns true, the difference is in the value.

Comment: So, `action` is executed either the option was found in the command line or not?

Comment: I don't think so. The action is executed if the flag is present, but the check you do is not proper. You should access the value of the flag to know if it was present or not.

Comment: @yegor256 it's not that `Action` is executed either way, it's that `SetTrue` specifically implies a default value (also `SetFalse`). Which makes sense: it's a flag, so why have a ternary boolean?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me at all (I always thought that an "action" is something that is executed in response to some event), but let it be, as long as it works :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the documentation of `contains_id`

> NOTE: This will always return true if `default_value` has been set. `ArgMatches::value_source` can be used to check if a value is present at runtime.

Now you might object that you're not using `default_value`, however you're using `ArgAction::SetTrue`:

> When encountered, act as if `"true"` was encountered on the command-line
>
> **If no `default_value` is set, it will be `false`**.

Emphasis mine.

So `ArgAction::SetTrue` implies `default_value=false`.

Therefore `bar` will *always* have a value, there's no need to check *whether* it does. Just fetch the value.

Comment: you were 26 seconds faster than me ;) nicely done!